# Why aren't my buttons moving down the page as expected?

Tags: jquery, html

I came up with a script for cloning a section of my questionnaire and when I click the "Add Customer" button it creates the clone, but the buttons stay anchored in place instead of moving down the page beneath the new clone.  Here's a JSfiddle of it https://jsfiddle.net/Optiq/ot010v4a/

the way I have the buttons set up is

```
<div id="bttnfrm" style="width:100%; height:32vh;">
    <button type="button" class="button" id="add_cus" style="width:22%; height:40px; float:right; margin-right:7%; clear:both; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#FC0;" value="Add Customer" >Add Customer</button>

    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

    <div class="texfrm_o" style="width:88%; height:auto;">
        <button type="button" class="button" id="p20_01_back" style="width:22%; height:40px; float:left; margin-left:22%; color:#FC0; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;" value="Back">Back</button> 
        <button type="button" class="button" id="p20_01_no" style="width:22%; height:40px; float:right; margin-right:22%; color:#FC0; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;" value="Next">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JQuery I used for the clone is

```
$("#add_cus").click(function(){

    var num = $('.clone_el').length;
    var newNum = new Number(num+1);
    var newClone = $("#cloner").clone().appendTo("#page20").after(newClone);

    newClone.attr('id',('cloner')+newNum).find("input, textarea, select, #cus_title").each(function(){

        var item = $(this);
        var type = this.type;
        var tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();

        if(type=='text'||tag=='textarea'){
            item.attr('name', item.attr('name')+newNum).attr('id', item.attr('id')+newNum).val('');
        }

            else if(tag=='select'){
            item.attr('name', item.attr('name')+newNum).attr('id', item.attr('id')+newNum).selectedIndex=0;
            }

            else if(item.attr('name')=='Customer_1'){
            item.attr('name',('Customer_')+newNum); 
            }

            else if(item.attr('id')=='cus_title'){
            item.text("Customer "+newNum);  
            }
        });
        //$("#bttnfrm").appendTo("#page20").after(newClone);

    });
```

As you can see I attempted to append the main button frame to the page beneath the new clone (I originally didn't have the "bttnfrm"div wrapping the buttons and came up with it to attempt the append) but that didn't work as expected.  On the first click the section moved down a hair, then on the second click it moved down beneath the 2nd clone and pretty much remained beneath the clones that were 2nd to last.

When I really thought about what I was doing it didn't make sense because I was regarding it as "the most recent clone" when it's really a process for creating the clone.  All in all this shouldn't even be an issue so before I go tacking my brain trying to concoct some crazy code just to make a button move I'd like to see if any of you can point out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are cloning fieldset tag with id=cloner, and your buttons are not inside the cloner id.

Comment: well that's because I don't want to clone the buttons, which it does in your adjustment and the cloned ones don't work.

Comment: So to make the use of newly made buttons, you need to modify the IDs of them and write appropriate jquery just the way you are managing the ids of select and text area.

Comment: actually I just created a new div to wrap the fieldset in and went to the jquery and appended the clone to the div.  Now it works perfectly fine, no need for all the extra monster scripting.